# Jest "cannot use import statement outside a module" error when testing Go JS PackedLayout in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest, gojs

I'm building a react app and was planning to using Go JS as a part of the app. However, I get this error when running the default `yarn test` that comes with create react app:

```
  /path/frontend/node_modules/gojs/extensionsJSM/PackedLayout.js:11
    import * as go from '../release/go-module.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import * as go from 'gojs'
    > 2 | import { PackedLayout } from 'gojs/extensionsJSM/PackedLayout'
        | ^
      3 | import { ReactDiagram } from 'gojs-react'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Grid.tsx:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:4:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
```

I believe the bug appears because of the line `import * as go from '../release/go-module.js';` in the Go JS `PackedLayout` file. I'm not quite sure as to how I am supposed to fix this. I assume that I'd have to somehow tell Jest to allow the import in the that particular file which is in node_modules.

I've tried adding `transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!gojs)']` to my `jest.config.ts` file but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As documented at:
https://gojs.net/latest/intro/extensions.html
and at:
https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/PackedLayout.html,
you should copy the extension file into your project and update its **import** statement to refer to the same GoJS library file.